# make gridView with multiple layout

Tags: android, object, gridview

i want to set an object in my gridView : the object called artefact can be an image or message, But after running my code and adding an object, the grid view doesn't appears. 
this is my code.
thisis my adapter

```
 public ArtifactAdapter(Context context,List<Artifact> artifacts)
{
    this.context =context;
    this.artifacts = artifacts;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    // Number of times getView method call depends upon gridValues.length
    return artifacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // LayoutInflator to call external grid_item.xml file


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Artifact artifact = artifacts.get(position);
    View gridView;
    gridView = new View(context);
    if (convertView == null) {

        ;
        switch (artifact.getType()) {
            case 1:

                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artifact_article, null);
                mTitle = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.titre);
                mPseudo = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.pseudo);
                mMessage = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.message_input);
                mTitle.setText(artifact.getTitle());
                mPseudo.setText(artifact.getPseudo());
                mMessage.setText(artifact.getMessage());


            case 2:
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artifact_image, null);
                mPseudo = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.pseudo);
                mImage = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageReceived);
                mPseudo.setText(artifact.getPseudo());
                mImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(artifact.getImagePath()));


        }
    }
    else {

            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }
    return gridView;
    }


}
```

this the activity

```
    GridView listArtifactView;
    List<Artifact> listArtifact = new ArrayList<>();
    ArtifactAdapter artifactAdapter = new ArtifactAdapter(this,listArtifact );
Artifact artefact = new Artifact(getPseudo());
                    artefact.setTitle(titre.getText().toString());
                    artefact.setMessage(message.getText().toString());
                    artefact.setType(1);

 listArtifactView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listArtifactView);

        listArtifactView.setAdapter(artifactAdapter);

                listArtifact.add(artefact);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here .But change your getView to something like this.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Artifact artifact = artifacts.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {

        switch (artifact.getType()) {
            case 1:

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artifact_article, null);
                mTitle = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.titre);
                mPseudo = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.pseudo);
                mMessage = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.message_input);
                mTitle.setText(artifact.getTitle());
                mPseudo.setText(artifact.getPseudo());
                mMessage.setText(artifact.getMessage());


            case 2:
               convertView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artifact_image, null);
                mPseudo = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.pseudo);
                mImage = (ImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.imageReceived);
                mPseudo.setText(artifact.getPseudo());
                mImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(artifact.getImagePath()));


        }
    }

    return convertView
```

See if it helps.